# How to pass the index of the iterable when using multiprocessing pool

Tags: python

I would like to call a function `task()` in parallel `N` times. The function accepts two arguments, one is an array and the second is an index to write the return result in to the array:

```
def task(arr, index):
    arr[index] = "some result to return"
```

To be explicit, the reason for the array is so I can process all the parallel tasks once they have completed. I presume this is ok?

I have created a multiprocessing pool and it calls `task()`:

```
def main():
    N = 10
    arr = np.empty(N)
    
    pool = Pool(os.cpu_count())
    pool.map(task, arr)
    pool.close()

    # Process results in arr
```

However, the problem is because `map()` is already iterable, how do I explicitly pass in the index? Each call to `task()` should pass in 0, 1, 2.... N.

Comment: Using `starmap`? But you can't share the `array` between multiprocessing

Comment: `pool.map` is calling `task` on each *element* of the array, not the array itself.

Comment: You want something similar to `pool.map(lambda x: task(arr, x), range(len(arr)))`.

Comment: @Corralien the array is just for `task()` to write each independent result, without any sort of memory corruption. Then after all tasks have been executed, I can iterate over the array and process the results together. At least, that is the intention. I don't write Python often, so there may be a flaw in this.

Comment: @chepner If you put it as an answer I'll try it and accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

def task(index, arr):
    print(index, arr)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 10
    arr = np.empty(N)
    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        pool.starmap(task, enumerate(arr))
```

Output:

```
0 6.9180446290108e-310
1 6.9180446290108e-310
2 6.91804453329406e-310
3 6.91804425777776e-310
4 6.9180448957438e-310
5 6.9180105412701e-310
6 6.9180443068017e-310
7 6.91804453327193e-310
9 6.9180449088978e-310
8 6.91804436388567e-310
```